# What does "Firebase Rules API" in API restriction section mean?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Does it apply to Firebase Security Rules? I am trying to restrict my key to Firestore only.

It is in Google Clout Platform.

1) click on any of the key generated.

[image]

2) see the drop-down item highlighted in red

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a link to whatever documentation you're looking at, as well as be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hey Doug, If I want to restrict the key to Firestore, do I have to turn on that "Firebase Rules API" as well?

Comment: Btw, "API key 3" (the very first key) in the first picture is generated for Google Map SDK for android.
The second key "auto-generated by Firebase" one is (I think) generated by Firebase when I create Firebase app for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Rules API doesn't have anything to do with client API keys.  That API is used for managing security rules, and end users would never do that.